# How can I set production build path in vue-cli?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, frontend, vue-cli

I'm using the vue-cli tool to develop vuejs apps, and I'm developing a server too, so i want to build the /dist folder in my server to send it to the browser as static, but I don't even know where the /dist folder is.

There is a webpack.prod.config.js file (I think is the webpack config for production) and in the path-output field I tried to wirte the path but didn't work.

Comment: See https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js and https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#outputdir

Comment: The `/dist` folder is the default output dir of your `build` script. So, unless you modify the output dir in your `vue.config.js`, running `npm run build` will create that folder for you, containing the production build. The contents of that dir are what you should deploy on a production server (after you build). And it is static.

Comment: @fxndvi Please take a look at my answer and let me know if it helped you or if you have any other related questions .

Comment: @fxndvi Please take a look at my answer below and mark as correct answer if it helped you , thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`/dist` is just a default setting by VueJS. If you want to modify this : as the documentation from VueJS states :

> Always use outputDir instead of modifying webpack output.path.

Create a `vue.config.js` as an optional config file that will be automatically loaded by @vue/cli-service if it's present in your project root (next to package.json).

The file should export an object containing options:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  // options...
}
```

As otheres already stated in the comments, use `outputDir` to specify the directory where the production build files will be generated in when running vue-cli-service build. Note the target directory will be removed before building (this behavior can be disabled by passing `--no-clean` when building).

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  outputDir : ''
}
```